# Error while running JUNIT testcase

Tags: java, junit, testcase

Hi I get the following error when i try to execute my JUNIT test case.
If somebody can help me with this, it would be of great help.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'commonValuesBackingBean' defined in class path resource [resources/ffms-storevisit-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cycleBackingBean' while setting bean property 'cycleBackingBean'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cycleBackingBean' defined in class path resource [resources/ffms-storevisit-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cycleManager' while setting bean property 'cycleManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cycleManager' defined in class path resource [resources/ffms-storevisit-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cycleBO' while setting bean property 'cycleBO'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cycleBO' defined in class path resource [resources/ffms-storevisit-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cycleDAO' while setting bean property 'cycleDAO'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cycleDAO' defined in class path resource [resources/ffms-storevisit-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sqlMapClient' while setting bean property 'sqlMapClient'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlMapClient' defined in class path resource [resources/ffms-common-spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.builder.xml.SqlMapConfigParser.parse(Ljava/io/InputStream;Ljava/util/Properties;)Lcom/ibatis/sqlmap/client/SqlMapClient;
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:275)
```

Eagerly waiting for the reply. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to do your research and be more succinct with your question.

Comment: A bit too much code, try reducing to an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). In any case, the clue for you is `Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.builder.xml.SqlMapConfigParser.parse(Ljava/io/InputStream;Ljava/util/Properties;)Lcom/ibatis/sqlmap/client/SqlMapClient;` - do you have two versions of ibatis-sqlmap on your classpath?

Comment: thanks for the reply Bystrup.There is only one version of ibatis-sqlmap in my class path. Bear with me, am new to programming

Comment: Did you find how to solve this problem??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, you have `ibatis-sqlmap` jar in your CLASSPATH. Then try open it (it's zip file) and check that there is `com/ibatis/sqlmap/engine/builder/xml/SqlMapConfigParser.class` file.

If it's not there then this means your jar is corrupted or was modified. If it's there then your CLASSPATH is wrong.